# iPhone video streaming application

Tags: iphone, video, stream, live, avfoundation

Can anyone help me to know how an app like this is done?

[Bambuser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bambuser/id344600665?mt=8)

Is the way to capture the camera's video stream using AVFoundation?

To be clear, I don't want to capture the video and save it, I want to stream it over a wireless network as an IP camera or over INTERNET to a web server.

and i take a look to some code sinppets just like [AVCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/)
and [technical note form apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1702.html)
but they were not helpful in the way i want

thanks,

Comment: Yes, start with AVFoundation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is another way, but the following method works for me:

1. using AVFoundation or other sdk to capture small fragment of video file
2. converting them to mp4 file
3. sending those files to server with order
4. convert them to ts format with a description ts file
5. using http live streaming to play them